# iOS Animation Array DESC

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation

i got the following code:

```
test.image = [testArray lastObject];
test.animationImages = testArray;
test.animationDuration = 1;
test.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[test startAnimating];
```

I am sure that one day i read that it is possible to "rewind" an animation but i can't find that solution any more - is there a better solution than ordering (DESC) the array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse the animation by accessing the reverseObjectEnumerator's objects:

```
testArray = [[testArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

You can then pass that into the animation:

```
test.image = [testArray lastObject];
test.animationImages = [[testArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
test.animationDuration = 1;
test.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[test startAnimating];
```

Or you could look into UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse, but i'm not sure that it's entirely what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `UIImageView`, which has limited animation possibilities. Reverting an animation is possible, but using the CoreAnimation based animations. You have two options, depending on the level of control you want on your anim.

- keep using `UIImageView`, and do what max_ suggests: modifying the images array so that the animation ends up being played as you want (if you need to play it forward then backward, you could change the array further to obtain that effect. Each image would have to appear multiple times in the array to achieve this)
- switch to `CALayer` animation. You would have to convert your array of `UIImages` to an array of `CGImages`, and create a `CABasicAnimation` operating on the `content` keypath of the layer. You would then have all the control you need, including the option to autoreverse the anim, because the animation object implements the `CAMediaTiming` protocol that allows that kind of stuff.